# Windows 7 won't install on an old laptop

Tags: windows, windows-7, laptop, bsod

I'm going to tell you a short backstory to help you understand the issue.

I've taken a laptop from a person and promised to make it run better. The laptop is old, and needs an older Windows version to run smoothly. Specifically we're dealing with ASUS R540S. Before I've done anything, the laptop was booting up into Windows 10, albeit very sluggishly, because there's only 2 gigs of RAM. So I used several official Windows 7 iso's that were lying around to create a bootable thumb drive, and tried those distros on the laptop. Unfortunately though, upon first boot the system is **ALWAYS** throwing blue screen, and this behavior can be observed on every Windows distro I've tried so far. The only difference is in that some distros show the blue screen, and wait for the user take some sort of action (like pressing power button), and other distros will briefly show you the BSOD screen and then restart leaving the user no chance to read what the error is. I've also tried booting into *Safe Mode* to no avail. I guess the system has to be properly set up before the *Safe Mode* is going to do the trick.

Attaching image of the bluescreen in question to the post.

So, can anyone suggest how can I solve this impasse?

[image: BSOD screenshot]

Comment: For a faster system, try Linux. On two PC's I use, I find Ubuntu boots in less than half the time that Win10 takes, opens programs such as LibreOffice and Firefox more than twice as fast, *and Ubuntu is steadily being updated for security,* unlike Win 7, past EOL. Let the other person decide: run Ubuntu right from USB *without* installing it. Only install it if it meets approval.

Comment: to be honest, every PC I've upgraded from 7 to 10 ran better on 10 - though they all had minimum 4GB ram - is there any possibility to upgrade RAM on this laptop?

Comment: The Linux is out of the question because the user won't be able to use that system. And updating the RAM is possible, but I'm not sure if the user is going to pay for that.

Answer (score 0):

The Stop 0x0000007e error in your case probably means that Windows 7 is
missing some essential driver for the ASUS R540S.

If Windows 10 works on the computer, you might consider
re-installing it.

For a stripped-down and quicker version of Windows 10,
you might try Tiny10.
The developer named NTDEV has trimmed-down Windows 10 to its bare
essentials, so it became a lightweight version of Windows 10.
It takes much less space, works even on low RAM computers,
and comes with no bloatware.

To find out what is Tiny10 and how to install it, see the article
[What is Tiny10 (Lightweight Windows 10) and How to Install It](https://beebom.com/what-is-tiny10-lightweight-windows-10-how-to-install/).

In the case that this article will disappear in the future,
here are the current download links:

- [Tiny10 32-bit](https://twitter.com/NTDEV_/status/1505654562992050178)
- [Tiny10 64-bit](https://twitter.com/NTDEV_/status/1505656808576372753)

Comment: Windows 10 was there only because someone had updated the system, but originally it used to run Windows 7 or 8 I believe. Is there a way to fix the driver issue with Windows 7 ?

Comment: I have checked, and the ASUS website has no driver downloads for this model. It only has a driver-updating utility, for the current (working) Window 7 computer. You will need the Windows 7 installation media that came originally with the computer, if the owner still has it.